# online graphs of common tween / easing functions?

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript-3, animation, function

Is there an online cheat-sheet to graphs of common tween / easing functions?  I want a bookmark I can refer to when picking a function for a tween (e.g., Quintic, Quadratic, "Bounce").  The only one I can do in my head easily is linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [one in the Tweener docs](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/misc/transitions.html) and since Tweener uses [Robert Penner's easing equations](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/), and so does pretty much every other tweening engine out there, so it should be good for all of them.